# Multiple nodes publishing to same topic in robot_localization package

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In robot_localization package, the nodes publish to /odometry/filtered (hardcoded). If there are 2 nodes - one for odom and one for map, which node is writing to this topic ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270006/multiple-nodes-publishing-to-same-topic-in-robot_localization-package/) by [shree](https://answers.ros.org/users/31228/shree/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The topic can (and should) be remapped. Otherwise, if you have two instances of robot_localozation, they will BOTH publish to the same output topic (not good). See below for remap example:

```
  <node name="RobotLocalizationCts" pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" respawn="true" output="screen" clear_params="true">
    <param name="frequency" value="20.0"/>
    <param name="print_diagnostics" value="false"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="3.0"/>
    <param name="two_d_mode" value="true"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
    <param name="publish_acceleration" value="false"/>
    <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_footprint"/>
    <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>
    <remap from="set_pose" to="robot_localization_cts/set_pose"/>
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="robot_localization_cts/odom"/>
    ...
    ...
    ...
  </node>
```

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0